# Como actualizar una vista parcial que esta dentro de una vista normal

Tags: asp.net, mvc, vistas

tengo una vista parcial que debe mostrar datos que provienen desde la BD, esta vista parcial esta dentro de una vista normal, lo que necesito saber es como hago para que cuando desde la acción de la vista principal retorne los datos, la vista parcial también obtenga datos y se actualice. Esto mas que todo lo necesito porque tengo varias vistas que dentro deben tener esta parcial y entonces desde cada vista debo llamar y actualizar esta parcial.

Nota. No se si estoy tomando el camino correcto para enfrentar este caso, ya que tengo varias vistas que tienen una parte de UI idénticas, es por eso que esta parte quiero ponerlo en parcial y llamarla desde todas las vistas, algo así como los famosos controles .ascx de webform.

Saludos cordiales a todos.

Comment: No se si lo puedes intentar con un UpdatePanel, puedes intentarlo. Saludos

Comment: update panel en MVC? hasta donde yo sabia no existe el update panel en mvc.